# Подключение и запросы в mysql через c++ builder

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

Привет, ребят помогите с рабочим примером подключения к БД, которая находится на  хостинге средствами с++ builder'а. Пытаюсь забавить якобы стандартную библиотеку

```
#include   <mysql.h>,
```

но компилятор орёт мол

> Unable to open include file 'mysql.h'.

Как там она же стандартная или я ошибаюсь? Спасибо.

Comment: Насколько я могу судить, Ваша проблема решается через: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-implementations.html

Однако я бы рекомендовал попробовать вот это: https://code.google.com/p/tiodbc/

и работать через ODBC. Вряд ли Вы используете Builder 6ой версии или старше, а значит работа идет под Windows, значит ODBC хороший выбор.